# Recursion: prefix sums

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, recursion

I'm solving a CodeWars kata.

[Link to the Kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5ce399e0047a45001c853c2b/train/javascript)

This is my code:

```
function partsSums(arr) {
    let bigSum = [];
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        bigSum.push(0);
    }

    while (arr.length >= 1) {
        let sum = arr.reduce((acc, ele) => acc + ele);
        bigSum.push(sum);
        partsSums(arr.shift());
    }

    return bigSum;
}
```

The correct answer should be: `[20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0]`

My function returns: `[ 20, 20, 19, 16, 10 ]`

Please point out where I'm wrong or my misunderstanding. Thank you!

Comment: just remove "=" in the while condition -> arr.length > 1

Comment: Your recursive call does absolutely nothing. It gets a number instead of an array, and the return is discarded. The "recursion" part of the question is kind of artificially glued on, without doing anything. The only reason it's not possible to outright comment it, is because the parameter calculation shortens the array by one.

Comment: Please include a description of the task as well as the example input you've listed an output for. Links can expire.

Answer (score 4):

You could reduce from the right side and add the value the the value at index zero.

```js
function partsSums(arr) {
    return arr.reduceRight((r, value) => [r[0] + value, ...r], [0]);
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

A speedy version

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
    let l = ls.length,
        result = [];

    result[l] = 0;

    while (l--) result[l] = result[l + 1] + ls[l];

    return result;
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when your array reaches length 0 in the loop, you're not actually appending anything to `bigSum`.  You can do that by explicitly adding it following your loop.

```js
function partsSums(arr) {
    let bigSum = [];

    while (arr.length >= 1) {
        let sum = arr.reduce((acc, ele) => acc + ele);
        bigSum.push(sum);
        partsSums(arr.shift());
    }
    
    bigSum.push(0);

    return bigSum;
}
console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

Comment: Also the `partsSums(arr.shift());` is redundant, and can be replaced with just `arr.shift()`

Comment: Yeah, this really isn't effectively using recursion TBH.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an actual recursion since you've tagged the question with that:

```js
function f(A){
  if (!A.length)
    return [0];
  const prev = f(A.slice(1));
  return [A[0] + prev[0], ... prev];
}

console.log(f([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

Answer (score 0):

with `for-loop` traversing end to start.

```js
function partsSums(arr) {
    const res = [];
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = arr.length; i > -1; i--) {
      res[i] = sum += arr[i] || 0;
    }
    return res;
}
console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using recursion,

```js
const ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10];

function partsSums(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 0) {
    return [0];
  }

  let temp_array = [];
  const sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0);
  arr.shift();
  temp_array.push(sum);
  temp_array = temp_array.concat(partsSums(arr));
  return temp_array;
}

console.log(partsSums(ls));
```